# LLDB warning: Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations on Windows 10

Tags: c++, llvm, breakpoints, lldb

after compiling my hello world program with `clang -g .\main.cpp -o .\main.exe` I then run and try to set a breakpoint but it does not resolve.

```
lldb .\main.exe
(lldb) target create ".\\main.exe"
(lldb) Current executable set to 'C:\Hello World\src\main.exe' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also I installed LLVM through chocolatey and I am running windows 10.

Comment: your format is wrong, correct one should be 'break main.cc:54'.

Comment: @FrankWang It's still unable to resolve the breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I just needed to register two dlls with regsvr32, *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll* & *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\DIA SDK\bin\amd64\msdia140.dll*